# How to assert error type json.UnmarshalTypeError when caught by gin c.BindJSON

Tags: json, validation, go, error-handling, go-gin

I'm trying to catch binding errors with gin gonic and it's working fine for all validation errors from go-playground/validator/v10 but i'm having an issue catching errors when unmarshalling into the proper data type.

Unsuccessful validation of a struct field will return a `gin.ErrorTypeBind` Type of error when using validator tags ( required, ...)

but if i have a struct

```
type Foo struct {
  ID int `json:"id"`
  Bar string `json:"bar"`
}
```

And the json i'm trying to pass is of a wrong format (passing a string instead of a number for id )

```
{
    "id":"string",
    "bar":"foofofofo"
}
```

It will fail with an error `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Foo.id of type int`

It is still caught as a `gin.ErrorTypeBind` in my handler as an error in binding but as i need to differentiate between validation error and unmarshalling error i'm having issues.

I have tried Type casting on validaton error doesn't work for unmarshalling :
`e.Err.(validator.ValidationErrors)` will panic

or just errors.Is but  this will not catch the error at all

```
    if errors.Is(e.Err, &json.UnmarshalTypeError{}) {
        log.Println("Json binding error")
    }
```

My goal in doing so is to return properly formatted error message to the user. It's currently working well for all the validation logic but i can't seem to make it work for json data where incorrect data would be sent to me.

any ideas?

edit :

adding example to reproduce :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type Foo struct {
    ID  int    `json:"id" binding:"required"`
    Bar string `json:"bar"`
}

func FooEndpoint(c *gin.Context) {
    var fooJSON Foo
    err := c.BindJSON(&fooJSON)
    if err != nil {
        // caught and answer in the error MW
        return
    }
    c.JSON(200, "test")
}

func main() {
    api := gin.Default()
    api.Use(ErrorMW())
    api.POST("/foo", FooEndpoint)
    api.Run(":5000")
}

func ErrorMW() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()
        if len(c.Errors) > 0 {
            for _, e := range c.Errors {
                switch e.Type {
                case gin.ErrorTypeBind:
                    log.Println(e.Err)
                    var jsonErr json.UnmarshalTypeError
                    if errors.Is(e.Err, &jsonErr) {
                        log.Println("Json binding error")
                    }
                    // if errors.As(e.Err, &jsonErr) {
                    //  log.Println("Json binding error")
                    // }
                    // in reality i'm making it panic.
                    // errs := e.Err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
                    errs, ok := e.Err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
                    if ok {
                        log.Println("error trying to cast validation type")
                    }
                    log.Println(errs)
                    status := http.StatusBadRequest
                    if c.Writer.Status() != http.StatusOK {
                        status = c.Writer.Status()
                    }
                    c.JSON(status, gin.H{"error": "error"})
                default:
                    log.Println("other error")
                }

            }
            if !c.Writer.Written() {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"Error": "internal error"})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

trying sending a post request with a body

```
{
  "id":"rwerewr",
   "bar":"string"
}
```

`interface conversion: error is *json.UnmarshalTypeError, not validator.ValidationErrors`

this will work :

```
{
  "id":1,
   "bar":"string"
}
```

and this will (rightfully ) return  `Key: 'Foo.ID' Error:Field validation for 'ID' failed on the 'required' tag`

{
"bar":"string"
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[update] : sice version [1.7.0](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/releases/tag/v1.7.0), which integrates [this PR](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/pull/2526), it is now possible to use `errors.Is` / `errors.As` on a `gin.Error`.

So you can write :

```
err := c.BindJson(&fooJson)

if err != nil {
var jsErr *json.UnmarshalTypeError
  if errors.As(err, &jsErr) {
    fmt.Println("the json is invalid")
  } else {
    fmt.Println("this is something else")
  }
}
```

---

[edit] : meh, it won't fix @Flimzy's answer : looking at [the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Error), `gin.Error` doesn't implement the `.Unwrap()` method.

You would have to first convert your error to a `gin.Error`, then check `ginErr.Err` :

```golang
// you can probably work with straight conversion from interface to target type :
if g, ok := err.(*gin.Error); ok {
    if _, ok := g.Err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); ok {
        log.Println("Json binding error")
    }
}

// or use errors.As() :
var g *gin.Error
if errors.As(err, &g) {
    var j *json.UnmarshalTypeError
    if errors.As(g.Err, &j) {
        log.Println("Json binding error")
    }
}
```

---

*my initial answer :*

(fixing @Fllimzy's answer)

1. use `errors.As`
2. since `json.UnmarshalTypeError` is a struct (not an interface), you have to explicitly disinguish between `json.UnmarshalTypeError` and `*json.UnmarshalTypeError`

Try running :

```golang
var jsonErr *json.UnmarshalTypeError  // emphasis on the '*'
if errors.As(e.Err, &jsonErr) {
    log.Println("Json binding error")
}
```

---

Here is an illustration of how `errors.As()` behaves :
https://play.golang.org/p/RVz6xop5k4u

Comment: FWIW : the implementation of `.Unwrap()` has been merged to the master branch of `gin` (PR [#2526](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/pull/2526)). Don't know what is planned release wise.

Answer (score 7):

`errors.Is` looks for an exact match (in your case, an empty instance of `json.UnmarshalTypeError`). Use `errors.As` instead:

```golang
var jsonErr *json.UnmarshalTypeError
if errors.As(e.Err, &jsonErr) {
    log.Println("Json binding error")
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/TwxNN33oaqR)

However, as @LeGEC has pointed out, this assumes that gin's errors conform to the standard `Unwrapper` interface, which they don't.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to offer advice with a complete reproduction case.

Comment: i have added an example

Comment: in such case would it be better to extend gin or use some kind of string comparaison of the error message ?

Comment: Avoid string comparison if at all possible. In this case, Gin exposes the info you need, just not through the standard channels. LeGEC's answer does a pretty good job of explaining how to do it.

Comment: It's also probably worth opening an issue/PR against gin to add that functionality. I'm a bit surprised it's not already done.

Comment: oh ok i missread him and thought his solution wasn't working. Yes i'm going to do this. From my research i think it's due to them moving from v8 or v10 for the validator i think the older validator behaved differently for this case and might not have been covered by tests

Answer (score 0):

```
  var (
       msg string
  )
  switch errs.(type) {
       case *json.UnmarshalTypeError:
           msg = errs.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError).Field + " type error."
       case validator.ValidationErrors:
           validationErrs := errs.(validator.ValidationErrors)
           for _, e := range validationErrs.Translate(trans) {
               msg = e
               break
           }
       default:
           msg = "unknow error"
  }
```