# Using validator to check if value is boolean

Tags: validation, go

I'm new to Go, so this might be very easy, but I can't find it. I have an entity `Page` with these two properties:

```golang
type Page struct {
    Title   string `form:"title" binding:"required"`
    Active  bool
}
```

Now, if you don't send a title we get a (not very pretty, but acceptable*):
`Key: 'Page.Title' Error:Field validation for 'Title' failed on the 'required' tag`.

Now, if I send this to the endpoint:

```json
{
    "title": "I'm a valid title",
    "active": "I'm not a boolean at all!"
}
```

We get this:
`json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Page.Active of type bool`

Which, IMO, is giving way too much info. What is the standard practice in Go to validate user input?

I was first making a `page-validor.go` with some checks, then I found this, but I'm not sure what is good practice in Go.
How do I validate this properly? Should I find check what is provided and then try to move it into the struct and validate the actual contents?

I am using [GinGonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation)
* I've found a way to unwrap the errors and make it nicer

Comment: Short answer: validation is done after the JSON is unmarshaled into the specified structure, so you can't check the data type with the validator. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278486/how-to-assert-error-type-json-unmarshaltypeerror-when-caught-by-gin-c-bindjson

Comment: Personally, `log` the parse error on your service side but return to the client a simple `400` (bad request) http status. If your API has [swagger docs](https://swagger.io/) (as it should) - you can provide example JSON schema of what your API expects. Returning precise reasons for why a client passed bad inputs is tedious task with little value IMHO.

Comment: I hate those "You did *something* wrong" errors, they often waste a lot of time, often about something stupid. By setting up some general validation it could some external developers a lot of time, and just as significant: It saves us debugging for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write custom JSON Unmarshaller method for the type `Page` and inside `UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte)` method, you can unmarshal the JSON bytes to `map[string]interface{}` and then validate the types you need with the JSON field keys.

An example of the JSON Unmarshaller looks like below.

```
type Page struct {
    Title  string `form:"title" binding:"required"`
    Active bool
}

func (p *Page) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    actv, _ := data["active"]
    if reflect.TypeOf(actv).Kind() != reflect.Bool {
        return errors.New("active field should be a boolean")
    }

    p.Active = actv.(bool)

    return nil
}
```

See the full example here in [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/4Ay-6ePmPWq).

Comment: Marked this as solution as this is the more native solution to what i asked, my answer below also works nice

Comment: Need more generic answer. This answer is very field specific.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I've implemented [Go-map-schema](https://golangexample.com/simple-json-type-checking-for-golang/).

```golang
var page Page
src := make(map[string]interface{})
json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &src)

results, _ := schema.CompareMapToStruct(page, src, nil)

fmt.Println(results.MissingFields)
fmt.Println(results.MismatchedFields)
```

This works simple with the standard notations for an struct:

```golang
type Page struct {
    Title  string `json:"title" validator:"required"`
    Active bool   `json:"metaRobotsFollow" validate:"required,bool"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use validator v10 available with Go

[validator documentation go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10)

For your use case you can use **boolean** validator
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Boolean

```
type Page struct {
  Title  string `json:"title" binding:"required"`
  Active bool   `json:"active" binding:"required,boolean"`
}
```

Below is sample Test case with one positive and negative

```
func TestPage(t *testing.T) {

tests := []struct {
    testName string
    input    string
    wantErr  bool
}{
    {
        testName: "positive test",
        input: `{
                 "title": "first book title",
                  "active": false
                }`,
        wantErr: false,
    }, {
        testName: "wrong boolean",
        input: `{
                 "title": "second book title",
                  "active": falsee
                }`,
        wantErr: false,
    },
}

for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.input, func(t *testing.T) {
        var p Page
        b := []byte(tt.input)
        err := json.Unmarshal(b, &p)
        assert.Nil(t, err, "got error %v", err)
    })
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is the combination with Gin. If I do a `c.BindJSON(&object)`, it will try to map the value "banana" to a boolean property, resulting in an error. I want to catch all errors and send them all in one go :)

Comment: you can implement custom validator and register with validation engine